# Using an abstract class with generics

Tags: java, generics

Trying to solve a warning in eclipse concerning usage of generics within an abstract class.

below is an example. Please neglect typos. I had to retype it. The code compiles fine, this is just an issue with generics.

here is my example abstract class using generics:

```
public abstract class myThing<T> { //myThings can be Integers, Character, or other

    //will compare a local stored myThing instance with the passed myThing instance
    public abstract boolean compare (myThing<T> theThing);

    //returns the locally stored version of myThing
    public abstract T getMyThing();

    //sets the value of the local instance of myThing
    public abstract setMyThing(T theValueOfMyThing)
}
```

now I want to create a class that stores and manages myThing Objects

```
public class myThingList<myThing> {
    private Vector<myThing> listOfMyThings; //a private array of myThings

    public myThingList() {  //constructor just initializes an empty array
        listOfMyThings = new Vector<myThings>();
    }

    //add a passed myThing object to the list 
    public void addThingToList(myThing x){
        listOfMyThings.Add(x);
    }

    //get a myThingObject at specified index from list
    public myThing getItemOnMyList(int idx){
        return listofMyThings.get(idx)
    }
}
```

so the problem is I am getting eclipse warning that `myThing` in `myThingList<myThing>` is hiding `myThing<T>`.

which I understand. MyThing is an abstract class and will not be defined until extended. so how do I resolve this? clearly I am doing something wrong here in my use of generics.

PS: I can get the program to run fine without them . just need to be careful with casting, but wanted to see if generics could help me clean the program up a bit.

THANKS

Comment: *Please neglect typos.* No, because a typo means that we do not have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your issue.

Comment: "The code compiles fine" - No, it doesn't.  `new Vector<myThings>();` `public abstract myThing<T>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `myThing<T>` you need to declare the type `T`. Remember, if you were creating, say a list of maps, you would declare it like `List<Map<String, Object>>`

In this case you have a couple of alternatives. Either make myThing's type explicit like this:

```
public class myThingList<myThing<SomeType>> {
    private Vector<myThing<SomeType>> listOfMyThings; //a private array of myThings

    public myThingList() {  //constructor just initializes an empty array
        listOfMyThings = new Vector<myThings<SomeType>>();
    }

    //add a passed myThing object to the list 
    public void addThingToList(myThing<SomeType> x){
        listOfMyThings.Add(x);
    }

    //get a myThingObject at specified index from list
    public myThing<SomeType> getItemOnMyList(int idx){
        return listofMyThings.get(idx)
    }
}
```

Or have myThingList generic too, like this:

```
public class myThingList<T> {
    private Vector<myThing<T>> listOfMyThings; //a private array of myThings

    public myThingList() {  //constructor just initializes an empty array
        listOfMyThings = new Vector<myThings<T>>();
    }

    //add a passed myThing object to the list 
    public void addThingToList(myThing<SomeType> x){
        listOfMyThings.Add(x);
    }

    //get a myThingObject at specified index from list
    public myThing<SomeType> getItemOnMyList(int idx){
        return listofMyThings.get(idx)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `myThing` as the *name* of the type parameter of the `myThingList` class. Use `T` instead.

Change

```
public class myThingList<myThing>{
    private Vector<myThing> listOfMyThings;
```

to

```
public class myThingList<T>{
    private Vector<T> listOfMyThings;
```

and use `T` similarly throughout that class.

#### OR

If `myThingList` is meant to only store `myThing` objects, delete it and just use `Vector<myThing>` instead.

Either way, your `myThingList` class is adding no value - it's just a thin veneer over a `Vector`.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you mean `Vector<myThing>` should be `Vector<T>` or `Vector< myThing<T> >`.

Comment: @tsolakp `Vector<T>`, but really the class should be deleted - it's doing nothing.